# Failed to install Calliope

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, calliope

I am trying to install the package calliope on python 3.7 using pycharm and I am getting this error that I don't understand.   I also tryed o install it via anaconda but still I am getting the same problem. Any help please would be highly appreciated. It is really imporant where I need this package to run a program about energy management.

```
Collecting calliope
  Using cached calliope-0.6.8.tar.gz (725 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting xarray<0.21,>=0.20
  Using cached xarray-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (845 kB)
Collecting plotly<3.11,>=3.10
  Using cached plotly-3.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41.5 MB)
Collecting netcdf4>=1.2.2
  Using cached netCDF4-1.6.2.tar.gz (777 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [33 lines of output]
  reading from setup.cfg...
  
   HDF5_DIR environment variable not set, checking some standard locations ..
  checking C:\Users\m.haddad\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in C:\Users\m.haddad\include
  checking /usr/local\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /usr/local\include
  checking /sw\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /sw\include
  checking /opt\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt\include
  checking /opt/local\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt/local\include
  checking /opt/homebrew\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /opt/homebrew\include
  checking /usr\include ...
  hdf5 headers not found in /usr\include
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\m.haddad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\m.haddad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\m.haddad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\ME920~1.HAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6qd6b_6t\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\ME920~1.HAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6qd6b_6t\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\ME920~1.HAD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6qd6b_6t\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 449, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 390, in _populate_hdf5_info
  ValueError: did not find HDF5 headers
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

### Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

1. Download HDF5 https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.12/hdf5-1.12.1/bin/windows/
2. Set the environment variable HDF5_DIR to `C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/<your unzipped location>`